# PostgreSQL substitute case sensitive variables in a command

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, case-sensitive

Hi I have some variables in a plpgsql script.  It's all case sensitive.

```
schema := 'myschema';
table_name := 'MyTable' 
column_name := 'MyColumn'
```

I need to put those variables in a simple statement:

```
select max(column_name) from schema.table_name.
```

I feel like I am battling the case sensitivity with PostgreSQL.  I basically need to recreate this:

```
select max("MyColumn") from myschema."MyTable";
```

For the life of me I can't get this work and am clearly too dumb for PostgreSQL.  Trying with EXECUTE(), EXECUTE() w/ FORMAT(), quote_indent() etc etc.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Got it with this gem

```
execute format('select max(%I) from %s.%I', column_name, schema_name, table_name);
```

Depressing that that took hours of my life...

Comment: in this case is good start by reading documentation - it takes just few hours and you can get imagine about possibilities, because programming in stored procedures is different than classic programming https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN

Comment: Use the format specifier `%I` for **all** identifiers, including the schema name.